# probability of smartphone lasting more than 2 years?

Tags: probability

I have trouble understanding probability in general but here's question: probability  of phone lasting less than 3 years is 0.75 and probability of it lasting more than 2 years and less than 3 years is 0.45, what is the probability of it lasting more than 2 years?. I'm writing a test on my own to prepare for exam and in the test correct answer is 0.7 and I got 0.6.

I thought that:
P(A) = 0.75 (probability of phone lasting less than 3 years)
P(B) = 0.45 (probability of phone lasting more than 2 and less than 3 years)
and P(C) = x (probability of phone lasting more than 2 years)

P(A) * P(C) = P(B)
0.75 * x = 0.45
x = 3/5 = 0.6.

Comment: There is no ground to think that P(A)*P(C)=P(B). Split up in 3 disjoint periods "less than 2 years, more than 2 years and less than 3 years, more than 3 years". They cover the whole timeline so the summation of the corresponding probabilities is 1.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity thanks

Comment: @drhab thanks I understand now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P(phone lasts between $2$ and $3$ years) $=0.45$

P(phone lasts $\geq 3$ yrs) = $1$ - P(phone lasts less than $3$ yrs) = $1 - 0.75 = 0.25$

Thus P(phone lasts $> 2$ yrs) $= 0.45+0.25= 0.7$

Comment: Thanks I got it

Comment: You're welcome !

Answer (score 0):

You have $P(x\le 3)=0.75$ and $P(2\le x\le 3)=0.45$. In addition, $$P(x\le 2)+P(2\le x\le 3)=P(x\le 3),$$
which gives you $P(x\le 2)$. All probabilities add to $1$, so this also tells you $P(2\le x)$.

Comment: i dont understand P(x≤2)+P(2≤x≤3) why are you adding those two, I mean it is intuitive to think that probability of it lasting less than 2 years plus probability of it lasting more than 2years and less than 3years will give you probability of it lasting less than 3years but I still dont understand why adding them. if could clarify this but it's still ok thanks a lot.